# Route path always rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I have a connected router setup as such:

```
<div>
  <Firebase />

  <LoginPopup />
  <RegisterPopup />
  <NavMenuContainer />
  <Navigation />


  <Route path={'/counter'} component={CounterView} />
  <Route path={'/router'} component={RouterView} />
  <Route path={'/calender'} component={CalenderView} />
  <Route path={'/'} component={HomeView} />
</div>
```

No matter which route I'm in (i.e. /CounterView or /RouterView) I always see 'HomeView' rendered at the bottom, in the case I'm in the root URL (/) I just see HomeView.

how do I make HomeView only show when in the root URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react router v4 you can do it by giving exact props, for further reading check [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md) out

```
<div>
  <Firebase />

  <LoginPopup />
  <RegisterPopup />
  <NavMenuContainer />
  <Navigation />


  <Route path={'/counter'} component={CounterView} />
  <Route path={'/router'} component={RouterView} />
  <Route path={'/calender'} component={CalenderView} />
  <Route path={'/'} exact component={HomeView} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `exact` to your `HomeView` route.

`<Route exact path={'/'} component={HomeView} />`

React Router v4 will display all routes that return true for `match.location.pathname.includes(path)`, unless you include `exact` on the route.

You can read about the [exact](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) property in the official [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) documentation.